# Get order collection between a date range magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have code for magento 1 site. Need to run on Magento 2.
I have used this code on outside of magento using this.

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require_once '../app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');


$fromDate = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', strtotime($_POST['fromdate1']));
$toDate = date('Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime($_POST['todate1']));
$order_status = $_POST['order_status1'];
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from'=>$fromDate, 'to'=>$toDate));
        $orders->addFieldToFilter('status', array('in' => array($order_status)));
        //echo $totalOrders = count($orders);
```

Comment: Can you please mention where you need the order Collection in custom block, helper or somewhere else ?

Comment: I need it on out side of magento .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use Below code in your Root file.

```
    <?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$params = $_SERVER;

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');


$now = new \DateTime();
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$OrderFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory');
$orderCollection = $OrderFactory->create()->addFieldToSelect(array('*'));
$orderCollection->addFieldToFilter('created_at', ['lteq' => $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')])->addFieldToFilter('created_at', ['gteq' => $now->format('2018-05-01 H:i:s')]);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($orderCollection->getData());
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code from any class within Magento. You need to change namespace, class name and function name as per your requirement:

```
<?php
namespace 'NAME_SPACE\OF\YOURCLASS';

class YOURCALSS extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    protected $_orderCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory 
    ) {
        $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);

    }

    }
   public function YOURFUNCTION()
   {
       $collection = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*');

       // You Can filter collection as 
       $this->orderCollectionFactory
            ->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array('gteq' => $fromDate))
            ->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array('lteq' => $toDate));
    }


   }       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try the blow code with your orders object

```
$orders->addFieldToFilter('status', array('in' => array($order_status)));
$orders->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array('gteq' => $fromDate));
$orders->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array('lteq' => $toDate));
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Create a Block file.
created_at field in  sales_order table represents the time of order creation in Magento 2 by default.

```
 <?PHP
 class OrderRange extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
 {
     public function __construct(
     \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
     \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory 
      $orderCollectionFactory,
      array $data = []
     ) {
          $this->orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
          parent::__construct($context, $data);
     }

     /* Order collection between start and end date */
     public function getOrderCollectionByDateRange(){
     $startDate = date("Y-m-d h:i:s",strtotime('2020-12-1')); // start 
     date
     $endDate = strtotime("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime('2020-11-1')); // end 
     date
     $orders = $this->orderCollectionFactory->create()
      ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from'=>$startDate, 
       'to'=>$endDate));
     return $orders;
  }
?>
```

Now, call Function from the template file:

```
 $orders = $block->getOrderCollectionByDateRange();
 if($orders->getTotalCount() > 0) { 
     foreach($orders as $_order) {
         $orderId = $_order['increment_id'];
         echo "<pre>";print_r($_order);
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the original filter syntax used in the question

```
[...]
    ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', [
        'from' => [$fromDate],
        'to' => [$toDate],
    ])
[...]
```